# How to run a shell script hosted remotely from a Gradle task

Tags: bash, gradle, github, build.gradle

Say you've got a simple bash script

```
echo $@
```

Hosted it in a public repo so you can access the raw file like

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh

Then you can run it in a shell like

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh) "hello"
```

I want to be able to achieve this within a gradle task. I've tried:

```
task testScript(type: Exec) {
  workingDir projectDir
  executable "bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh) 'hello'"
}
```

and

```
task testScript(type: Exec) {
  workingDir projectDir
  executable "bash"
  args "<(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh)" 'hello'
}
```

and

```
task testScript(type: Exec) {
  workingDir projectDir
  commandLine "bash", "<(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh)", "hello"
}
```

To no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original command, `<(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh)` isn't resolved by the `bash` command you call, but by the shell from which you call it, the actual command being executed is something like `bash /dev/fd/63 "hello"`.

Gradle is no shell and will just call `bash` with the string `"<(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh)"` as argument without further processing.

You need to find a command that doesn't need to be expanded by the shell it's being called from. For instance, handling your current command as plain text and using another shell to resolve it :

```
bash -c 'bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh) hello'
```

In conclusion I believe the following should work :

```
task testScript(type: Exec) {
  workingDir projectDir
  executable "bash"
  args "-c", "bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../test.sh) hello"
}
```